# Apache Airflow - Prescript rerun at each task of the dag and date change

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am new with using airflow.
I noticed that if you define a global variable (timestamp) in the code, this value will change for each task. For example in the very basic example bellow, I define a variable **now** but each time I print it in a task, this value changes.

```
from datetime import timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
import time

now = int(time.time() * 1000)
RANGE = range(1, 10)


def init_step():
    print("Run on RANGE {}".format(RANGE))
    print("Date of the Scans {}".format(now))
    return RANGE


def trigger_step(index):
    time.sleep(10)
    print("index {} - date {}".format(index, now))
    return index


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': days_ago(1),
    'retries': 2,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=15)
}

with DAG('test',
         default_args=default_args,
         schedule_interval='0 16 */7 * *',
         ) as dag:
    init = PythonOperator(task_id='init',
                          python_callable=init_step,
                          dag=dag)

    for index in init_step():
        run = PythonOperator(task_id='trigger-port-' + str(index),
                             op_kwargs={'index': index},
                             python_callable=trigger_step, dag=dag)

        dag >> init >> run
```

Is it a normal behavior ? Is there a way to change it ?

Comment: I see no question here, you are stating a fact, but where is your problem?

Comment: It seems to be an issue because then I cannot share a date between tasks

Comment: Did you look into XComs for sharing data between tasks? https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#xcoms

Comment: It looks that this will do the job but it is a bit too much for a so basic issue. For this specific use case I feel it is not the workaround to use